# How can I make my slide content not to overlap with each other?

Tags: jquery

This code basically shows hidden divs to slide up I just don't want them to overlap with each other whenever any of this button is clicked I want any div that is previously up to slide down. I would really appreciate it if you can also shorten my jquery code.

```
    <html>
<title></title>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function( $ )
 {

          // Get a reference to the container.
            var container1 = $( "#content1" );
            // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
            $( ".button1" )
            .click(
                function( event ){
                    // Prevent the default event.
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // Toggle the slide based on its current
                    // visibility.
                    if (container1.is( ":visible" )){
                        // Hide - slide up.
                        container1.slideUp( 500 );
                    } 





                    else {
                        // Show - slide down.
                        container1.slideDown( 500 );


                    }
                }
            );



            // Get a reference to the container.
            var container2 = $( "#content2" );
            // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
            $( ".button2" )
            .click(
                function( event ){
                    // Prevent the default event.
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // Toggle the slide based on its current
                    // visibility.
                    if (container2.is( ":visible" )){
                        // Hide - slide up.
                        container2.slideUp( 500 );
                    } 





                    else {
                        // Show - slide down.
                        container2.slideDown( 500 );


                    }
                }
            );


             var container3 = $( "#content3" );
            // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
            $( ".button3" )
            .click(
                function( event ){
                    // Prevent the default event.
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // Toggle the slide based on its current
                    // visibility.
                    if (container3.is( ":visible" )){
                        // Hide - slide up.
                        container3.slideUp( 500 );
                    } 





                    else {
                        // Show - slide down.
                        container3.slideDown( 500 );


                    }
                }
            );


              var container4 = $( "#content4" );
            // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
            $( ".button4" )
            .click(
                function( event ){
                    // Prevent the default event.
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // Toggle the slide based on its current
                    // visibility.
                    if (container4.is( ":visible" )){
                        // Hide - slide up.
                        container4.slideUp( 500 );
                    } 





                    else {
                        // Show - slide down.
                        container4.slideDown( 500 );


                    }
                }
            );


        }   





        );




</script>




</head>

<body>

<style type="text/css">
    #content1 
    {
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    color: red;
    }

    #content2 
    {
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    color: blue;
    }

    #content3
    {
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    color: brown;
    }

    #content4 
    {
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    color: green;
    }
  </style>


<div id="wrapper">
<input type="button" class="button1"></input>
<input type="button" class="button2"></input>
<input type="button" class="button3"></input>
<input type="button" class="button4"></input>


<div id="content1">
First div
</div>

<div id="content2">
second div
</div>

<div id="content3">
Third div
</div>

<div id="content4">
Fourth div
</div>



</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can we get your HTML too please?

Comment: Hi there I edited the code so basically I don't want them overlapping and if you can shorten my jquery code that is much appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to know exactly what you need here, but you could use the jQuery `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` callback function to tell you when the animation is complete:

```js
$('#containerz').slideUp('slow', function() {
  $('#containers').slideDown('slow');
});
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkyxyzeo/1/). Hope it helps.

If you are looking for the animation to happen at the same time, you could try this:

```js
$(".button1").click(function(event) {
  $('#containerz').slideUp('slow');
  $('#containers').slideDown('slow');
});

$(".button2").click(function(event) {
  $('#containers').slideUp('slow');
  $('#containerz').slideDown('slow');
});
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkyxyzeo/2/).

**Extended answer:**

Please see new demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7vb0gff/1/).

There was some duplicate code in your example so I have refactored it by splitting the duplicated code out into a seperate function:

```
function showContent(container) {
    if (container.is(":visible")) {
        // Hide - slide up.
        container.slideUp(500);
    } else {
        // Show - slide down.
        container.slideDown(500);
    }
}
```

I have also added a `hideContent` function that will hide any content `divs` as required:

```
function hideContent(div1, div2, div3) {
    div1.slideUp(500);
    div2.slideUp(500);
    div3.slideUp(500);
}
```

I have also refactored your CSS as again there was some duplication. So I have added a content `class` to your content `divs`:

```
<div id="content1" class="content">First div</div>
```

And added the `content` class to your CSS. So if you need to make changes to this CSS, you only have to do it in the one place rather than for each of your content `divs`:

```
.content {
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}
```

I have added a new function to enable / disable the buttons when clicked:

```
function setButtons(inactiveBtn) { 
    $('.button').prop('disabled', false);
    inactiveBtn.prop('disabled', true);
}
```

New demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7vb0gff/9/).

Comment: I edited my post I just don't want the contents to overlap thank you!

Comment: So you're trying to create a 'stacked' effect?

Comment: I don't know what you mean all I want is only 1 div or content shows at a time.

Comment: Please see my extended answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want the div that will be replaced to just disappear can you make it to slideDown? Sorry i'm just new thank you.

Comment: Also how do i disable any of this button once I clicked it and then when I click any of the other button it will enable again? Please and thank you.

Comment: Yep exactly how I wanted it you just made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('[class^=button]').on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent default behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        // retrieving button number
        var buttonNb = $(this).attr('class').substr($(this).attr('class').length - 1); // assuming the button has only one class which is 'button*' (where * is either 1 or 2)

        // assigning variables
        if(buttonNb == 1) {
            var $contUp = $('#containerz');
            var $contDown = $('#containers');
        } else if(buttonNb == 2) {
            var $contUp = $('#containers');
            var $contDown = $('#containerz');
        }

        // do the job
        if($contUp.is(':visible')) {
            $contUp.slideUp(500, function() {
                $contDown.slideDown(500);
            });
        } else {
            $contDown.slideDown(500, function() {
                $contUp.slideUp(500);
            });
    });

});
```

Comment: where is my .button1 and .button2 i'll simply just copy paste this.

Comment: @DaleFlordeliz: It's binded on the click event of the DOM element that will have a class that starts with `button`. I just refactored the code. Just assure you that the button have the class `button1` and `button2`.

Comment: Hi there I edited it can you please fix my code and if you can shorten it that is much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

Working Fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/gwe81ka0/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/co0s5zyh/

Code1:

```
var containerz = $("#containerz");
var containers = $("#containers");

 $( "#button1" ).click(function(){

          if (containerz.is( ":visible" )){
              containerz.slideUp( "slow",function(){
                            if (containers.is( ":hidden" )){
                                    containers.slideDown( "slow" );
                            }
                                 }
                                );
          } 
 //         if (containers.is( ":hidden" )){
  //            containers.slideDown( "slow" );
  //        }
          }
   );
$( "#button2" ).click(function(){

          if (containers.is( ":visible" )){
              containers.slideUp("slow",function(){
                           if (containerz.is( ":hidden" )){
                                containerz.slideDown("slow");
                           }
                               }
                                );
          } 
//          if (containerz.is( ":hidden" )){
//              containerz.slideDown("slow");
//          }
          }
   );
```

Code2:

```
var containerz = $("#containerz");
var containers = $("#containers");

 $( "#button1" ).click(function(){

          if (containers.is( ":hidden" )){
              containers.css('z-index',99);
              containerz.css('z-index',98);
              containers.slideDown( "slow",function(){
                            if (containerz.is( ":visible" )){
                                       containerz.slideUp( "slow" );
                            }
                                      }
                                  );
         }
          }
   );
$( "#button2" ).click(function(){

         if (containerz.is( ":hidden" )){
              containerz.css('z-index',99);
              containers.css('z-index',98);
              containerz.slideDown( "slow",function(){
                            if (containers.is( ":visible" )){
                                       containers.slideUp( "slow" );
                            }
                                      }
                                  );
         }  
          }
   );
```

Comment: Edited my post please reread it basically I only want one div at a time I do not want any of them to overlap

Comment: @Dale Flordeliz Edited the answer. Didnt understand your problem properly, so I made two Jsfiddles. Hope that solves it.